# Updating cell of table via Jquery is not working

Tags: jquery

I have following functionallity

1. User has a table with entries
2. He can click per row on an edit button
3. A modal view opens
4. User enters values
5. On click on save button these values PLUS the id from the table will be transfered to my controller
6. **TODO, see below.**

Right now I have everything implemented up to my controller.

After my AJAX request get a success message from my Controller I want to update the table cell.

My function updateCell should find the row and update it with the new values.

Since I was not able to just replace every cell value I thought about just replacing the whole row with the new content.

But if I execute the function, actually nothing happens.

If I use

```
$("#" + userID).html("test);
```

It works.

**What I need.**

Best would be to just update the particular cell values instead of just replacing the whole row. But I wonder due to runtime it makes no difference to replace the whole row instead of cell values?

Can anyone please tell how to achieve what I want either with replacing the whole row or just replacing the cell values which are displayed to the user?

Here is my JS:

```
  function updateCell(userID, userName, userAge) {
    $("#" + userID).html("<td text=" + userName + "class=\"username\"></td>\n" +
        "                    <!--/*@thymesVar id=\"getTradableBTC\" type=\"java.lang.Double\"*/-->\n" +
        "                    <td text=" + userAge + " class=\"age\"></td>\n" +
        "                    <!--/*@thymesVar id=\"getTop\" type=\"java.lang.Double\"*/-->\n" +
        "                    <td text=" + userID + " class=\"id\"></td>\n" +
        "\n" +
        "                    <td>\n" +
        "                        <div class=\"btn-toolbar\" role=\"toolbar\">\n" +
        "                            <!-- Button trigger modal -->\n" +
        "                            <div class=\"btn-group mr-2\" role=\"group\" aria-label=\"First group\">\n" +
        "                                <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm\" data-toggle=\"modal\"\n" +
        "                                        data-target=\"#myModal\" data-th-id=\"${person.getId()}\">\n" +
        "                                    Edit\n" +
        "                                </button>\n" +
        "                            </div>\n" +
        "                            <div class=\"btn-group mr-2\" role=\"group\" aria-label=\"Second group\">\n" +
        "                                <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm\" id=\"delete\">Delete\n" +
        "                                </button>\n" +
        "                            </div>\n" +
        "                        </div>\n" +
        "                    </td>");
}
```

Here my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-12">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Age</th>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <!--/*@thymesVar id="productList" type="java.util.List"*/-->
            <tr th:id="${person.getId()}" th:each="person : ${elementList}">

                <td th:text="${person.getName()}" class="username"></td>
                <!--/*@thymesVar id="getTradableBTC" type="java.lang.Double"*/-->
                <td th:text="${person.getAge()}" class="age"></td>
                <!--/*@thymesVar id="getTop" type="java.lang.Double"*/-->
                <td th:text="${person.getId()} " class="id"></td>

                <td>
                    <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
                        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                        <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal"
                                    data-target="#myModal" data-th-id="${person.getId()}">
                                Edit
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="Second group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" id="delete">Delete
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="addElement">Add Element</button>
    <button class="btn btn-light" type="button" id="DeleteAll">Delete all Elements</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you get an error in the console?
Your function has userName as parameter but you use username in your string concat.

Comment: true, I updated the question. It didn't change the problem

Comment: The function does exactly what its supposed to do. You have to put the text you want to display in between the tags `<td>text</td>`. You could also give classes to the td tags (e.g. name, age and id) and select with jquery `$("#" + userID + " .name")` and so on.

Comment: To change name for example `$("#" + userID + " .name").text("newName")`

Comment: I tried it with $("#" + userID + " .username").text("newName"); in my function but it has no effect.

Comment: did you add the class to the td's? I tried it locally